# AJAX GET from PHP server works after second call only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

First of all - I have just started learning PHP with some experience with jQuery. Secondly - I tried solving this for days, don't crucify me, please...

I need to get data from the database using jQuery AJAX call to PHP server. It works, but the problem is that it does so only after the second call (click).

The form is loaded asynchronously to body and, when I follow the link to it, the URL is *.../index.php#tr_dom*. I've noticed that, when I first click the button, the URL goes from *.../index.php#tr_dom* to *.../index.php?order=ASC#tr_dom* and empties the page, but URL stays the same. Then, I go to that specific link again. The form loads again and only now, when I click the button that calls the function in question - it works as expected.

Can someone please help clarify this issue? Relevant code below.

**PHP DBBrocker:**

```
function prikaziTroskoveDomacinstva($username, $sort_val, $sort_order) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM (trosak t INNER JOIN trosak_domacinstva td ";
            $query .= "ON t.trosak_id = td.trosak_id) INNER JOIN datum d ";
            $query .= "ON t.datum_id = d.datum_id INNER JOIN vrsta v ";
            $query .= "ON v.vrsta_id = td.vrsta_id ";
            $query .= "WHERE username = '".$username."'";

            if (isset($sort_val)) {
                $query .= " ORDER BY ".$sort_val;
            }

            if (isset($sort_order)) {
                $query .= " ".$sort_order;
            }

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

            $this->chckResult($result); //not relevant in this context

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo ("<br>".$row['iznos'].
                    "<br>".$row['opis'].
                    "<br>".$row['datum'].
                    "<br>".$row['naziv']);
            }
        }
```

**PHP controller:**

```
include_once("DBBroker.php");
$dbb = new DBBroker();

if (isset($_GET["function"]) && !empty($_GET["function"]) && $_GET["function"] == "tr-dom-select") {
        $dbb->prikaziTroskoveDomacinstva("Nikolic", $_GET["sort_val"], $_GET["sort_order"]);
    }

$dbb->closeConnection();
```

**JQuery functions:**

```
var loadForm = function (hRef) { //loads the form on click of the <a>
        document.location.hash = hRef;
        $("#main").empty().load("../includes/layout/"+hRef+".php");
}

var selectTrDom = function(responseFn) { //gets data from server
    var sortVal = $("#tr-frm select").val();
    var sortOrder = $('#tr-frm input[name="order"]:checked').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url: '../includes/layout/main.php',
        dataType : 'text',
        data : {
            'function' : 'tr-dom-select',
            'sort_val' : sortVal,
            'sort_order' : sortOrder
        },
        success : function(data) {
            responseFn(data);
        }
    }); 
}

var responseCallback = function(data) { //displays data on ajax success
    $("#message-box").html(data);
}
```

**And in `$(document).ready(...)`**

```
//load the right form on click, pass correct hRef

$(document).on('click', '#tr-frm #btn-sort', function(evt) {
    selectTrDom(responseCallback);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#tr-frm #btn-sort').click(function(event) {
    selectTrDom(responseCallback);
});
```